# PyroCMS infinite scrolling / pagination path issue

Tags: jquery, pagination, scroll, infinite, pyrocms

I'm trying to implement the infinite scroll jquery plugin (http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) by applying it to the blog page of a PyroCMS (http://pyrocms.com) install. However, I'm running in to an issue with repeating entries as the plugin seems to assume that the pagination structure is going to be page/1, page/2 and so forth, while PyroCMS builds the URLs as page/, page/10, page/20 and so forth. Is there any way to correct this?

I'm triggering the plugin using the following settings:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('#content').infinitescroll({              
                    state           : {
                        currPage    : "10"
                    },
                    loading         : {
                        img         : "/img/loading.gif",
                        msgText     : "<br /><br />",
                        finishedMsg : "All done."
                    },                  
                    nextSelector    : "div.pagination ul li.next a",
                    navSelector     : "div.pagination",
                    contentSelector : "#content",
                    itemSelector    : "#content div.blog_post",                 
                    pathParse       : ["/index.php/blog/page/", "/"]
                    }, function() { window.setTimeout(infinite_scroll_callback(), 1); } );
                });
```

I was thinking editing the blog module's routes file could possibly work, but I'm not sure how to restructure it to get the module to use the page number versus the quantity of blog posts when constructing the pagination URLs. The contents of the routes file is, essentially:

```
// public
$route['(blog)/(:num)/(:num)/(:any)']   = 'blog/view/$4';
$route['(blog)/page(/:num)?']               = 'blog/index$2';
$route['(blog)/rss/all.rss']                = 'rss/index';
$route['(blog)/rss/(:any).rss']         = 'rss/category/$2';
// admin
$route['blog/admin/categories(/:any)?']     = 'admin_categories$1';
```

I think the source of the problem is that the plugin is simply expecting a different pagination structure than the CMS provides. If there's anything you can do to help, I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

i think you will need to edit the blog.php controller, and create new method/function for the infinite scroll to use.

Then just point the:

pathParse       : ["/index.php/blog/page/", "/"]

to the new controller

pathParse       : ["/index.php/blog/**newcontroller**/", "/"]

Comment: Hmm, would amending the existing method work? It currently uses $this->data->pagination = create_pagination('blog/page', $this->blog_m->count_by(array('status' => 'live')), NULL, 3); can I change that count to the number of pages forced via pagination vs. the count of entries?